# Cannot configure webcam for Cheese

Tags: webcam, dconf, cheese

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a 64 bit Intel-based machine. I have a PCI video grabber card installed and working. I also have a USB webcam which works fine under VLC and I can see the cam details with v4l2-ctl. I want to use the cam with MS Teams, and I was told to test with Cheese. Cheese can only see the grabber card.

I have tried using dconf-editor to change the Cheese config to look at the USB cam, both by name and as `/dev/video1` but it defaults back to the grabber as soon as Cheese is launched. I have tried *dconf-editor* as user and via `sudo` and also tried *dconf update* in both cases. **It still defaults back**. Is there another layer below *dconf* that I need to set?

Comment: OK back to this problem again.  Some research has lead me to udev and reading the Man Page for udev8, also Egidio Docile's "Tutorial on how to write basic udev rules in Linux".  I have written a .rules file as follows: \# puts Lifevideo pci card onto "Video1"
# and USB webcam onto "Video0"

BUS="pci", ID="05:00.0", NAME="Video1"
BUS="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}="046d",SYSFS{idProduct}="08af", NAME="Video0"

Comment: sorry, can't drive this version of markdown - will read some more...